# Meteor: body backgroundimage

Tags: css, templates, meteor, helper

I have a Meteor project with different Routes.

In one of my css files there is:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #888;
    background-image: url("/images/bg.png");
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Now I want a different background image for my body when I go to a different Route and render different templates.
Is there a Meteor-way solution to handle this?
I know jQuery and this is not what I want, so please no non-reactive stuff, thanks.

Is it possible to define a global helper for my body like

```
<body class="{{classWithDifferentBackground}}">
```

which returns the right class for each route in a reactive way? So that I could have my different CSS-classes handle the backgroundimage for the body...

Thanks for your help and thoughts on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by setting the class manually. Good places to do so include router and layout template methods. For example:

```
Template.someLayout.onRendered(function() {
  $('body').addClass('someLayoutBody');
});

Template.someLayout.onDestroyed(function() {
  $('body').removeClass('someLayoutBody');
});
```

Comment: There is probably no other solution than this... Global helpers only react inside of templates, not outside like in the body-tag. Thanks anyways!